# UPDATE table if data exists in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables. Table A contain this data

```
column_1  column_2
 A        SAND
 B        Mixed
 C        ROUGH
```

Table B contain this data

```
column_1 column_2
         SAND
         Mixed
         Mixed
         SAND
         ROUGH
```

I'm trying to write a SQL update query that can update data from column_1 in table A into column_1 in table B based on matching value from column_2 in table A and table B

The output should be like this:

```
    column_1 column_2
     A        SAND
     B        Mixed
     B        Mixed
     A        SAND
     C        ROUGH
```

I tried many ways but can't seem to get it right. Can anyone help me how to achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you are using `sqlsrv`, i believe this is `sql server`.

```
update b
set b.column_1 = a.column_1
from tableB b
inner join tableA a on a.column_2 = b.column_2
```

Comment: Thanks!! it works. so short and simple. I wasn;t expecting this

Answer (score 0):

do join and update

```
update b
set b.column1=a.column1
from tablea a join tableb b on a.column2=b.column2
```